# Yii2 Kartik SideNav How to set 'active' option

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, kartik-v

I have Kartik's SideNav (http://demos.krajee.com/sidenav-demo/profile/default) working properly by setting the url's to controller/action, but don't understand how to set the active option so that the menu stays open and the correct menu item stays selected.

I've tried setting 'active'=> 'controller/action' (see below) as well as
'active' => 'controller/action/default#demo' but to no avail.  When I do set it as 'employee/employee-dashboard/default#demo' it does keep that one tab highlighted but won't change the others when I do it the same way on those tabs.  The original was set to 'active'=> 'home' which I assume is just the action but that didn't work for me either.

```
            $type = SideNav::TYPE_DEFAULT;
            $heading = '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i> Employee Menu';
            $item = '/employee/employee-dashboard/default#demo';

echo SideNav::widget([
                'type' => $type,
                'encodeLabels' => false,
                'heading' => $heading,
                'items' => [
                    // Important: you need to specify url as 'controller/action',
                    // not just as 'controller' even if default action is used.
                    //
                    // NOTE: The variable `$item` is specific to this demo page that determines
                    // which menu item will be activated. You need to accordingly define and pass
                    // such variables to your view object to handle such logic in your application
                    // (to determine the active status).
                    //
                    ['label' => 'Dashboard', 'icon' => 'home', 'url' => Url::to(['/employee/employee-dashboard', 'type'=>$type]), 'active' => ($item == '/employee/employee-dashboard/default#demo')]

                    ['label' => 'Paycheck Info', 'icon' => 'book', 'items' => [
                        ['label' => '<span class="pull-right badge">10</span> W2 Forms', 'url' => Url::to(['/employee/w2-form', 'type'=>$type]), 'active' => ($item == 'w2-form')],
```

Comment: I just want some clarifications. You want to set menu row (which is a dropdown) to `active` and it should stay opened with all of its children?

Comment: Yes.  See the demo page at http://demos.krajee.com/sidenav-demo/profile/default for proper operation.  Currently, I can click on any menu item and it goes to the correct page, but the menu item doesn't stay highlighted and if it's an expanded menu with children, the menu closes.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'active'=>($item == 'about')

where
    $item = Yii::$app->controller->action->id;


This is how i used

<?php

    $item = Yii::$app->controller->action->id;
    echo SideNav::widget([
        'type' => SideNav::TYPE_DEFAULT,
        'heading' => 'Options',
        'items' => [
            [
                'url' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
                'label' => 'Home',
                'icon' => 'home',
                'active'=>($item == 'index')
            ],
            [
                'label' => 'Help',
                'icon' => 'question-sign',
                'items' => [
                    ['label' => 'About', 'icon'=>'info-sign', 'url'=>Yii::$app->homeUrl.'site/about', 'active'=>($item == 'about')],
                    ['label' => 'Contact', 'icon'=>'phone', 'url'=>Yii::$app->homeUrl.'site/contact', 'active'=>($item == 'contact')],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ]);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks!  That's a very elegant solution that allows you to use it from a layout file for many pages.  The only other solution I found (just a few minutes ago), I'm going to post below, forces you to use it on individual pages.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I found if you want to set the active menu item on a per page basis is:

Create a separate view file (e.g. sidemenu.php) with just the SideNav widget, which accepts a parameter called 'currentPage'.

```
echo SideNav::widget([
    'type' => SideNav::TYPE_DEFAULT,
    'heading' => 'Options',
    'items' => [
       [
          'url' => Url::toRoute('/site/index'),
          'label' => 'Home',
          'icon' => 'file',
          'active'=>($currentPage == 'home'),
       ],
       [
          'url' => Url::toRoute('/site/about'),
          'label' => 'About',
          'icon' => 'file',
          'active'=>($currentPage == 'about'),
       ],
```

Then in the view page where you are rendering the menu, set the `currentPage` property -- for example:

```
echo $this->render('sidemenu', ['currentPage'=>'home']);
```

or
    echo $this->render('sidemenu', ['currentPage'=>'about']);